# Will I have to reformat my disk that is running ubuntu 13.04 64bit after upgrading my Motherboard and CPU? details inside

Tags: installation, upgrade, 13.04, 64-bit

Im currently running ubuntu 13.04 64 bit on a custom computer that consists of a asus a8n-sli deluxe mobo and a AMD athlon 64 FX-60 Dual Core processor x 2 with 4 gb ram. The OS works great and supports my gpu, sound card and everything else. I'm upgrading my Motherboard and cpu today to a gigabyte 990fxa-ud3 motherboard, a AMD fx-8350 cpu with 16gb ram. Everything else in the system will stay the same. Questions: Will I have to reformat my disk after installation?

Answer (score 2):

No, so long as your hardware is all Linux compatible it should boot right up.

Answer (score 1):

> Will I have to reformat my disk after installation?

No.

2 remarks...

1. Do make a backup of your private documents. You never know what might go wrong.
2. Disable any extra drivers you might have installed before removing the current motherboard and gpu.

Answer (score 0):

I disabled the extra drivers, the motherboard, cpu, and memory have been installed.  When I boot up my computer it gives the gigabyte screen and then ends up with a screen titled: GNU GRUB version 2.00-13ubuntu3 with 4 options:
ubuntu
advanced options for ubuntu
memory test (memtest86+)
memory test (memtest 86+, serial console 115200)

When I select the top "ubuntu" it ends up on a screen that says:
Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:
-Boots args (cat /proc/cmdline)
   - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
   - Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
-Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; 1s /dev
ALERT! /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg--root does not exist. Dropping to a shell!

BusyBox v1.20.2 (Ubuntu 1:1.20.0-8ubuntu1) built in shell (ash)
Enter 'help" for a list of built in commands.

(initramfs)_

A few side notes:

- I can't enter help on that screen, the keyboard doesn't seem to work.

  - I took out the sound card as I only had 1 pci slot and used it for my wireless card (that wireless card was already in the system (the on board sound is fine for me)
- I  took out both DVD drives because they were IDE.
- It's UEFI DualBIOS if I need to go into setup to change anything

Everything else is the same.

AM I suppose to make a new  thread?